# Using select all script for filtered table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, selectall

I am using [this](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/examples.php) ([file here](http://kirsehirilan.net/js/tablo.js)) script and i am using check all script in first row for my checkboxes. But first when I filtered for a column, this script selected checkboxes at hidden rows, too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select_all').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }else{
         $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

$('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
    if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
});
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: can you share the relevant html code as well?

Comment: Try `$('.checkbox:visible')`

Comment: @Malk, this works perfectly. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. My new codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#select_all').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $('.checkbox:visible').each(function(){
            this.checked = true;
        });
    }else{
         $('.checkbox:visible').each(function(){
            this.checked = false;
        });
    }
});

$('.checkbox:visible').on('click',function(){
    if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox:visible').length){
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
});
```

Thanks everybody...

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `:visible` selector to leave out the checkboxes that have been filtered. https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$('#select_all').on('click',function(){
    var doCheck = this.checked;
    $('.checkbox:visible').each(function(){
         this.checked = doCheck;
    });
});
```